# Error when using Entity Framework partial class

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4, partial-classes

I am using a partial class to add methods to a context object.

```
namespace AddressCleansing
{    
  public partial class service
  {
    internal void Save()
    {
      Result result = new Result();
      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AccountCode))
      {
        string newAccountCode;
        result = CreateAccount(out newAccountCode);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I attempt to load a web page (and not one that uses the code) there's a compilation error:

> **Description**: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> **Compiler Error Message**: CS1061: 'AddressCleansing.service' does not
>   contain a definition for 'AccountCode' and no extension method
>   'AccountCode' accepting a first argument of type
>   'AddressCleansing.service' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

The app is using Code First Entity Framework.

Comment: Make sure the partial class definitions have the same class name and are in the same namespace.

Comment: Both of these appear correct. The app compiles successfully. The error only appears when trying to load a page.

Comment: Where have you written `AccountCode()` function?

Comment: AccountCode is a column in the table database (i.e. a property of the service entity object)

Comment: Probably you don't have column AccountCode in your database